# How can I mutate my state without having to reload the entire json object via the API

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using reactjs with redux, and on the UI I am displaying categories along with the products associated to them.

When the user moves a product to another category, I don't want to have to reload the entire JSON file as I am doing currently because the JSON is actually pretty large.

How can I mutate this JSON file by just removing the productId from the catProducts collection of one category and adding the productId to another categories catProducts collection.

```
{
  "shop" : {

    "categories": [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "category1",
        "catProducts" : [
          {
            productId: 123
          }          
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "category2",
        "catProducts" : [
          {
            productId: 456
          }          
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "category3",
        "catProducts" : [
          {
            productId: 789
          }          
        ]
      }
    ]

  }

}
```

Below is my action and reducer, as you can see I am reloading the entire category with products each time a product is moved.  **All I need to do is after the API call is made, mutate my state by removing the productId from one catProducts and add it to another.**  How can I do this?

Actions:

```
moveProduct: (data) => {
  return dispatch => {
  var url = '....'; // api to move the product in db
  axios.post(url, reqArgs)
    .then(function(resp) {
      dispatch(Actions.fetchCategoriesAndProducts(data.shopId));
    });
  };
},
```

Reducer:

```
case Constants.FETCH_CATEGORIES_AND_PRODUCTS:
  return {...state, fetching: false, shop: action.data };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have an index `fromIndex` representing the `categories` array index to move a product from, `toIndex` representing the `categories` array index to move a product to, and `productId` of the product to move, you could do it like this:

```js
const data = {
  shop: {
    categories: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "category1",
        catProducts: [
          {
            productId: 123
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "category2",
        catProducts: [
          {
            productId: 456
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "category3",
        catProducts: [
          {
            productId: 789
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

const fromCategoryIndex = 0;
const toCategoryIndex = 1;
const productId = 123;

const categories = [...data.shop.categories];

categories[fromCategoryIndex] = {
  ...categories[fromCategoryIndex],
  catProducts: categories[fromCategoryIndex].catProducts.filter(
    product => product.productId !== productId
  )
};

categories[toCategoryIndex] = {
  ...categories[toCategoryIndex],
  catProducts: [...categories[toCategoryIndex].catProducts, { productId }]
};

console.log(categories);
```

Comment: Where do I do this, in my reducer?  Like in the case statement?